# Filter with jsonpath-ng

Tags: python, jsonpath-ng

Working with the following json data:

```
{
    "data": 
        {
            "level1":
                [
                    {
                        "levelName": "level11",
                        "cost": 1,
                        "child":
                            {
                                "childName": "first",
                                "status": "running"
                            }
                    },
                    {
                        "levelName": "level12",
                        "cost": 2,
                        "child":
                            {
                                "childName": "second",
                                "status": "asleep"
                            }
                    }
                ]
        }
}
```

A jsonpath search/filter using the expression
`"$.data.level1[*][?(childName=='first')]"`
correctly locates the data.
However, using the expression
`"$.data.level1[*][?(levelName=='level11')]"`
returns blank

How do I search at the "levelName": "level11" level?

In the latter case, if I have the "levelName": "level11" in the json data at the same level as "childName": "first", the search works successfully.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you only need to slightly change your syntax to select the node in question:

```
$.data.level1[?(@.levelName="level11")]
```

We are already in the `level1` array and can directly filter.